# How to show download progress for large files from Google Drive in .NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-drive-api

I am creating a file download method in my .NET 7 Web API using the following code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadById([FromRoute] string id)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await drive.Files.Get(id).DownloadAsync(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "test.zip");
}
```

When I try to download a large file, the page appears to freeze until the download into MemoryStream is complete, then a Save File dialog popups. I want to see a download progress in the browser while the download is in progress. How can I archive it?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("long-running-task")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Run()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
    Response.ContentLength = 10;

    var sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        await sw.WriteAsync("1");
        await sw.FlushAsync();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

this will show progress bar